# Remove ordinal in dates using datetime

Tags: datetime

Using `datetime` package in `article` class, how can I remove the ordinal (that is, st in 1st, nd in 2nd etc) from British dates, please. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[level,long]{datetime}
...
\title{Testing the Boundaries}
\author{}
\date{}
```

gives

> Wednesday 3rd May, 2017.

How can I remove the "rd"?

Answer (score 7):

Rather use the newer [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) and change the language-specific `ord`inal setting to be `omit`ted (other options are `level`, `raise` and `sc`; see [the English language module documentation](//mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-english/datetime2-english.pdf)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

You could also redefine `\DTMenglishordinal` to just print its argument (and not add anything else):

```
\renewcommand{\DTMenglishordinal}[1]{\number#1 }
```

Comment: Or `\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Ah. I honestly tried `ord=none`. :)

Comment: Sorry, in hindsight that would've been a better value :-)